# How can I sort this array of arrays by the second value in each array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following array:

```
[[1, 2], [44, 1], [18395, 3]]
```

Which I obtained by using this code:

```
current_user.friends_products.where("units.primary_image_id IS NOT NULL").group_by{|u| u.creator_id}.map {|k,v| [k, v.length]}
```

I want to sort the array by the second value of each array from greatest to least. So, this is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
[[18395, 3], [1, 2], [44, 1]]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [#sort_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) with the second element descending:

```
x = [[1, 2], [44, 1], [18395, 3]]
x.sort_by { |a, b| -b }
#=> [[18395, 3], [1, 2], [44, 1]]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this [`Array#sort`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-sort) block:

```
[[1, 2], [44, 1], [18395, 3]].sort { |a, b| b[1] <=> a[1] }
# => [[18395, 3], [1, 2], [44, 1]]
```

Comment: Please, never use `sort` for a keyed sort (i.e. never use `sort` when `sort_by` will do). Not only is it more readable, it is also more efficient.

Comment: @JörgWMittag My benchmarks show `sort` is about 2.5x faster than `sort_by`: https://gist.github.com/augustt198/b73aeab4bd76833c3d65. I can understand the readability though.

Answer (score 3):

```
[[1, 2], [44, 1], [18395, 3]].sort_by(&:last).reverse
```

Answer (score 2):

```
arr =[[1, 2], [44, 1], [18395, 3]]
arr.sort_by{|x,y|y}.reverse
# => [[18395, 3], [1, 2], [44, 1]]
```